# Google App Engine suddenly giving 404 for static files

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When I tried accessing my GAE app today the server said that it couldn't find the static HTML file I wanted; it had been working fine yesterday, and I hadn't made any changes to `appengine-web.xml` or `web.xml`.  The GAE logs say `No handlers matched this URL.` for the static files.

[**Irrelevant details removed**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I *had* changed `appengine-web.xml`; specifically, I'd removed `<include path="**"/>` from the `static-files` section.  Putting that back in fixed the problem.

Comment: So what about self-accepting this self-answer so the issue clearly shows up as closed? That's stackoverflow recommended etiquette.